# Excel : compare several columns (about 10) values and only highlight the first one that's different

Tags: vba, compare, match, return-value, formulas

I am new at coding and I have to work on an excel document that has about 40,000 rows and 50 columns. I have deleted about 35 columns that have specifications that don't matter to me.

In the first 14 columns there are values that define different products. Those defintions can be numbers as a specification for a product's power or serial number, or letters as a specification for the product's name or origin.
I have sorted out all my columns using a personalized filter, ordering them first according to column 1, then column 2, and so on...
On the 15th column, there are dates which account for the date at which the product was first launched.

What I am trying to do is to compare all the first 14 columns in each row and only get the one that was launched first. As I have deleted 35 columns, a lot of the products are the same (they differ by specifications in other columns).
I have tried recording a macro or using formulas in the 16th column to return a value if the values in columns didn't match but it's always comparing to the first value (first row) and I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Would anyone mind sending me a few tips on how to get there ?

Thank you a lot for your help (and sorry if there were any English mistakes)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the condition, that decides, what product falls into same "category" is matching values in first 14 columns. I would then suggest a macro, that will step by step filter the list by every possible combination of the 14 columns, sort by the date (ascending) and then pick the top most date. But you are going to have to write such macro. There is no way to record it. However, recording could help you with the basic operations

Comment: Yes that's it, if the values are the same in the first 14 categories, then I compare the dates and only pick the most ancient one. OK I will try a macro by recording an example and try filterig first and then pick the most ancient date. Thanks

Comment: I've made a mix of VBA and formulas using the IF(AND(...)) and rendering values of 1 or 0 depending on wether the columns matched or not. I think it's working now thks :)

Comment: Perfect, you are welcome. You can post an answer to your question, so that it can be useful to someone with similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found a solution which would be (as I have to repeat this in several excel files): 
Record a macro for the filtering, something like this :

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Tableau1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Tableau1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range( _
        "Tableau1[Car]") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Tableau1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("Tableau1[Model]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Tableau1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("Tableau1[Motor]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Tableau1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("Tableau1[Carburant]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Tableau1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range( _
        "Tableau1[Techno]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

... and so on !

Then I created a new column so that it would say either 1 or 0 dependig on wether all the rows were identical with a formula of `IF(AND(C2=C3;D2=D3; ... ; O2=03);1;0)` and finally I entered in a final column a formula saying that if there was a 0 to the left, the date of this row should be taken into account, if not the date 1/01/1900 would appear. Then by filtering this row and taking off the 1900 date, I obtained what I wanted.

I hope it's clear.